# Recursive function's value between iterations

Tags: functions, recursive-algorithms

I have the following function:

$$ x_{t=1} = x_{t=0} - \frac{c_1* y_{t=0}^{c_2} }{x_{t=0} + y_{t=0}}$$

$c_1$ and $c_2$ are constants, and we know the values $x_{t=0}$ and $y_{t=0}$. How can I calculate $x_{t=0.1}$ for example?

Comment: Welcome to math.se

Comment: Your question is not clear. Can you be more specific on the domain of the variables? Is that a recurrence relation?

Answer (score 0):

Your recurrence defines $x_1$ in terms of $x_0, y_0, c_1$ and $c_2$. However, it does not specify any kind of behavior for $x_t$ with $t \in (0,1)$. Hence, these values are undefined. Perhaps if you need to assume some form for them, one could consider linear interpolation. Then you set
$$
x_t = tx_1 + (1-t)x_0, \quad \forall t \in (0,1),
$$
and in particular,
$$
x_{0.1} = 0.1x_1 + 0.9x_0 = \frac{x_1 + 9x_0}{10}.
$$